# How to integrate a new payment gateway with odoo 10 based on javascript or API

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, odoo-10

I'm integrating Kushki (https://docs.kushkipagos.com/kushki-libraries/libraries/front-end/web/cajita#kushki-cajita) Payment Gateway with Odoo 10.

I'm following Paypal and Ogone modules but I see these ones are kind of diferent, both of them go direct to the payment gateway form. But Kushki don't have such form, it instead gives me a javascript box (an embeded javascript called cajita).

This cajita can be shown in Odoo website, but I don't know how to pass parameters to it: amount, order id, etc, to execute payment.

This is the embeded javascript they provide:

```
<script src="https://cdn.kushkipagos.com/kushki-checkout.js"/>
<form id="kushki-pay-form" action="confirm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_id" value="123"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var kushki = new KushkiCheckout({
    form: "kushki-pay-form",
    merchant_id: "1000000529876546576745015519790458",
    amount: "1.14",
    currency: "USD",
    payment_methods:["credit-card"],
    is_subscription: false,
    inTestEnvironment: true
});
</script>
```

How can I show this form after click on "Pay now" button in the ecommerce? And how to pass parameters to the form?

Thanks a lot in advance.